# How do I fire a callback function for each and every item in a drop menu?

Tags: javascript

I have a drop down menu `<UL>`, with many menu items `<LI>`, some of which items are parents("daddy") of a sub-menu.

I have a callback function that looks like this:

```
mouseenterCallback: function(evt) {
    var $thisLI = evt.target;

    if ($thisLI.hasClass("daddy")) {
        alert("daddy");
    }
}
```

In this test, the alert **only** shows when the mouse enters the main menu title ... but **not** for each and every `<LI>`

How can I make the former **and** the latter happen?

*/signed/*   bewildered

Comment: There is no `hasClass()` method on elements. Where does that come from? How is `mouseenterCallback` bound to your events?

Comment: Learning to search is a super power when you are just starting out.  Even super vague search terms like "*jquery every li*" turn up plenty of hints ...

Comment: @Don'tPanic OP hasn't tagged this [tag:jquery]

Comment: No, but they are using `hasClass()`. And considering it is a hint about search keywords, I think they'll get the idea, even if they need to `s/jquery/javascript/`.

Comment: I could be terribly wrong here, but I am not looking for obj.each. I am seeking code that works with the event object that is automatically passed to a callback function. FWIW I did an alert on evt.target.nodeName and got BODY and UL. BTW, the UL = the top #menubar. So, JS is stopping at the top of the tree and not continuing down to the LIs for each menu item. I could do a obj.each on the passed event - but that would consume a lot of time. From top to bottom: 1) BODY, 2) UL#menubar 3) LI.drop, 4) LI. Thanks bunches for listening

Comment: One more thing = the callback function is bound to the #menubar. I do need to think about binding to the $(“li”) collection

Comment: Maybe I misled you, sorry, I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do with the mouseover. You can certainly attach a handler to all `li`s: `$('#menubar li').on('mouseenter', mouseenterCallback);`. Or you can attach just one handler to the `ul`, and iterate through the `li`s: `$('#menubar').on('mouseenter', function(e) { $(this).find('li').each(function(i) { mouseenterCallback(e); }) });`

Comment: As mentioned in the comments it isn't clear if you're using jQuery or not (`hasClass` is jQuery, but your question isn't tagged jQuery).  I've used jQuery above.

Comment: Not panicing **yet**. I bound the `#menubar` container via `$Mbar.bind ('mouseenter',   itsOptions.mouseenterCallback);` Then,   `mouseenterCallback: function(evt) {  $thisLI = evt.target;  }`. But it appears that `evt.target` is the `#menubar` and not the individual `li`  which begin with the top-most menu title `li.drop` and further down the tree the individual menu items below the menu title.

Comment: I did try binding to the collection `$("li")`, but that did not work. Back to thinking more. I liked your `$('#menubar').on('mouseenter', function(e) { $(this).find('li').each(function(i) { mouseenterCallback(e); }) });`. So I'm exploring that.

Comment: If `$Mbar` represents `#menubar`, that's where the event handler is bound, and it is event target is the whole thing.  If you bind to individual `li`s, you'll be able to identify which one triggered the handler.  Also note that in a jQuery handler, `$(this)` represents the element that the triggered the handler.  This might be useful: https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/ohk8vz5s/

Comment: 1) I finally gave up making all callbacks work on same target. Some would work with evt.target = $(“li”) and others world work with $(“#menubar”). EG, animation stuff would work with menubar and mouse over would work with li. 

2) Anyway, it’s onto football and at 4:00 am back to plug-ins and messages

Comment: I’m finished. Thanks to Don’t Panic. BIG TIME THANKS!